# Can't get WebRTC audio track data on receiving end of a peer connection (in native C++ code)

Tags: webrtc, peer-connection

I'm trying to send video & audio data using `PeerConnection` from one native (C++) endpoint to another.  I've figured out how to get the video frames on the receiving endpoint, but can't seem to get the audio data.

The `MediaStreamInterface` I get on the receiving endpoint, in the `OnAddStream` callback, correctly reports having both video and audio track.  In order to get the audio data I've tried implementing the `AudioTrackSinkInterface` and calling `AddSink()` on the received audio track, but the `OnData` callback never gets called.  And for some reason the audio track's `GetRenderer()` method returns NULL...  So I have no clue how I can extract the audio data from the stream.

Thanks.